# Поиск резидентных программ в памяти

Tags: ассемблер, прерывания

Здравствуйте! Мне необходимо написать резидентную программу на языке Assembler, которая искала бы в памяти другие резидентные программы и выводила их имя. Нашла, что можно просканировать цепочку записей MCB при помощи функции 52h, но не понимаю, как там найти резидентные программы.

Comment: В общем случае задача нерешаемая. Резиденты, ставящиеся не через функцию ДОС, не будут обнаружены. Да и ставящиеся через ДОС - если программа освободила блок среды, то имя взять будет неоткуда. И - Вы уверены, что надо написать ***резидентную*** программу?

Comment: @Akina, а если идея в том, чтобы написать именно резидентную программу, которая бы перехватывала `int 27h`, `31h/21h`?

Comment: @PinkTux Что-то мне крайне сомнительно, что смысл задания именно таков... нет, теоретически я могу представить резидентный монитор, который всплывает по хоткею и показывает список текущих резидентов - но ни суть программы, ни суть оговорок от этого не изменятся.

Comment: Программа должна быть именно резидентной. Вот так звучит мое задание: TSR -программа должна распечатывать те TSR -программы, у которых не освобождена память Environment.Но пока мне нужно написать хотя бы часть с поиском резидентных программ. Единственное, что пока нашла, это сканирование MCB, а как перехватывать int 27h вообще не знаю.
.

Answer (score 0):

DOS (а и MCB и "резидентные программы") наводят на мысль о ней - однозадачная ОС.
То есть все программы, кроме вашей, которым принадлежат блоки памяти, и будут резидентными. И идя по цепочке memory control block, вы ищите блоки, которые не принадлежат ОС (слово со смещением 1 в цепочке, "владелец", не равно 0). Указанный там "владелец" - это PID процесса. Пишите уникальные PIDы в строку или массив - вот это и будет список "резидентных" (запущенных в настоящий момент) программ.
Не записываете в него PID своей программы, если знаете, как его получить.

[Вот тут](http://e-dok.narod.ru/msdos/book/gl03-05.html) есть пример на assembler, проверить не могу, DOS у меня нету.